# How to use sed to replace strings in piped input with command outputs using regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, audit

I'm trying to use sed to properly parse the output of auditd records. These have encoded hex, long timestamps and UID/AUID which I need to decode/translate via commands.

I am using pipes as I have to ship this across to the system journal.
I have gotten this far:

```
sed -r "s@msg=([A-Z0-9]*)\$@msg=$(xxd -r -p <<< \1)@"
```

Sample input:

```
[IRRELEVANT STUFF] msg=7468697320697320612073616D706C652074657374
```

The problem is that sed is not "unfolding" the capture group and the nested command receives the wrong argument/input.

xxd should be receiving `7468697320697320612073616D706C652074657374` and not `\1`

I have tested this in isolated fashion and that is indeed what is happening.

HELP! Thanks!!

Comment: What is that literal `$` in pattern?

Comment: That is the string/line termination character for matching with the regex

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the double quotes. You could try something like this `sed -r "s@msg=([A-Z0-9]*).*|.@\1@g" | xxd -r -p`. (there is no `$` and `g` flag is added.)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, as I am trying to edit in line, the full output (post replacing) would be fed into a different command

Comment: The output of sed would be `\1`. So right string would be passed to `xxd`.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for doing s/old/new, that is all, for anything else just use awk. With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk '
match($0,/(.*msg=)([[:alnum:]]+)$/,a) {
    cmd = "xxd -r -p <<< " a[2]
    $0 = a[1] ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "ERROR")
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }
'
```

The above is assuming the syntax for calling your `xxd` command is exactly what you had in your sed script. I don't have `xxd` on my system but here's using `wc -c` instead to show how the script works:

```
$ wc -c <<< 7468697320697320612073616D706C652074657374
43

$ awk '
match($0,/(.*msg=)([[:alnum:]]+)$/,a) {
    cmd = "wc -c <<< " a[2]
    $0 = a[1] ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "ERROR")
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }
' file
[IRRELEVANT STUFF] msg=43
```

Comment: This looks fantastic and exactly what I need but I can't seem to be able to run it, I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: I had an extra paren. I fixed that and updated my answer to show the script working but calling a different shell command that I have on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
sed -r "s/.*msg=([A-Z0-9]*).*/xxd -r -p <<< \1/e" input
```